# Deleting Winzip Command Line Add On 2.2 vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to delete a file like winzip command line using this code

`Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzuninst.exe wzcline C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzclun.dll")`

When I run it on cmd it says Bad name or number. Can someone clarify it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid command line.

If you want to run a program you use wshshell.run.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*"
```